# How to use UICollectionView with several buttons inside

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have this pet project with a bunch of buttons inside, every button has an action on touchDown and its working without issues. But the problem is when I have 10x10 or more and I drag the UICollectionView, such buttons can't be touched anymore! They won't respond to any event and I can't realise whats happening.

See a screenshot
[image]

This game must have several cells, it can be huge but I don't think 100x100 is huge enough for any modern IOS cellphone, its not having more than 60mb ram memory usage so I don't think its the problem.
See some of my code snippets.

My view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UICollectionView!

let squareButton: SquareButton = buttonSquare(row: row, col: col, frameWidth: self.myView.frame.width, worldSize: worldSize).squareButton
                    squareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.squareButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                    squareButton.tag = buttonCount
                    self.myView.addSubview(squareButton)
```

My struct to build those buttons

```
struct buttonSquare {
        var row: Int
        var col: Int
        var frameWidth: CGFloat
        var worldSize: Int
        var squareButton: SquareButton {
            get {
                let square = Square(row: row, col: col)
                let squareSize:CGFloat =  frameWidth / 20.0 //CGFloat(worldSize)
                let squareButton = SquareButton(squareModel: square, squareSize: squareSize, squareMargin1: 1.0);
                squareButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
                // squareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.squareButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchDown)
                return squareButton
            }
        }
    }
```

My button code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SquareButton : UIButton {

    var squareSize:CGFloat
    var squareMargin:CGFloat
    var square:Square

    init(squareModel:Square, squareSize:CGFloat, squareMargin1:CGFloat) {
        self.square = squareModel
        self.squareSize = squareSize
        self.squareMargin = squareMargin1
        let x = CGFloat(self.square.col) * (squareSize + squareMargin1)
        let y = CGFloat(self.square.row) * (squareSize + squareMargin1)
        let squareFrame = CGRect(x:x, y:y, width:squareSize, height:squareSize)
        super.init(frame: squareFrame)
        self.backgroundColor = squareModel.live ? .black : .white
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    }

    func change(_ state:Bool) {
        self.backgroundColor = state ? .black : .white
        square.live = state
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

[image: I can't click on buttons beyond that position]

Xcode 9, swift 4
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using a `UIButton` treat every square to be `UICollectionViewCell`, use `collectionView:didSelectRowAt:` to do what ever you want to when the square is selected

Comment: Can I change background colour ? Maybe I should try it.

Comment: `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` and the cell can have a `selectedBackgroundView`

Comment: I cannot override function collectionView any tips?

Comment: Why do you want to override collectionView, just set properties on collectionView

Comment: hi, I did what you sugested. In fact it works perfectly with exception that UICollectionView only flow horizontally or vertically, I need both because my grid can have 10x10 cells. Nevertheless your sugestion helped me for redesign the app. Now I'll create a new CustomLayout that provides me such kind of zooming and dragging, but all cells can be clicked now and working.